# Paraview : How into plot over line data selected, just save this data?

Tags: plot, save, paraview

I want just save one data over line in Paraview. I make :

- Load data
- Cell Data To point Data
- Plot data over line
- I select my variable

But When I save data in the format `.csv`, I would like to save only the values that I select. But save.data writes every variable 14 of which I don't want. Is there a way to save only selected values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply a filter such as `Pass Arrays` filter to remove the arrays you're not interested in. `Pass Arrays` filter was improved for ParaView 4.2. If you're going to use it, I'd suggest using ParaView 4.2 to avoid some annoyances with the filter.

Answer (score 1):

I fine one solution, when I load data, I just load data that I want.